# Unreal c++ SetRelativeLocationAndRotation how to translate rotation values from editor to Rotator?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

ive been trying to attach some text render components to a box, having text showing at 4 sides. but i cant figure out how calculate the rotator.

When i use my editor to correct the rotations it should be `(Pitch=90.000000,Yaw=0.000000,Roll=-90.000000)` so i tried putting the same values into the FRotator

```
textTop->SetRelativeLocationAndRotation(FVector(0.0f, 0.0f, 10.1f), FRotator(90.0f, 0.0f, -90.0f));
```

but now in the editor it shows `(Pitch=90.000000,Yaw=13.262696,Roll=-166.737289)`

Clearly i'm doing something wrong, and cant figure out what. please guide me on how to do this properly so my text can be displayed correctly

Comment: I'm guessing your textTop is a component within an actor that has its own transform. When you set the relative rotation, that is relative to the actor, not to the world (like in the editor). Instead, try using SetWorldLocationAndRotation

Comment: @BasinhetVeld ah, didnt think of that. thanks